# How to make Siri read the return value of a Pythonista script?

Tags: siri, sirishortcuts, pythonista

I wrote a python script that checks the trains for me from home to the office and vice versa. For now it accepts input like tomorrow, today, around X hour etc. and it works like a charm. However the problem is when I say: "Hey Siri, check me a train from home to the office tomorrow around 7" it opens the Pythonista app and shows the result in a console, so I have to read it myself.

As you can tell I'm lazy so I would prefer Siri to read it for me.

How can I get the Siri to read the output without the Pythonista app being opened? It should execute the code in a background, somehow pass the values back to the shortcut, which would allow Siri to read the output.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonista has a `speech` module that you can use to speak your results aloud. Different languages and locales are availble, and as underneath Apple APIs are used you even get the same old Siri voice.